# Error returning an object literal in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in my application as i am following lynda.com tutorial to learn Node.js I get some error on line where it says origin: o saying "unexpected token"

```
var number, origin, destination;

exports.setNumber = function(num){
    number = num;
}

exports.setOrigin = function(o){
    origin = o;
}

exports.setDestination = function(d){
    destination = d;
}

exports.getInfo = function(){
    return 
    {
        number: number,
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination
    };
};
```

I have no idea what is the error, i am following the tutorial line by line on lynda.com

Comment: There is no syntax error, still, try to add semicolon after exports sentences

Comment: @wZVanG: Yes, there is see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return 
{ ... }
```

is equivalent to

```
return;
{ ... }
```

because of JavaScript's [**automatic semicolon insertion**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion). If you want to spread the return value over multiple lines, you have to start the object literal on the same line:

```
return {
  // ...
};
```

---

You got the error because

```
{
    number: number,
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination
};
```

is interpreted as a [**block**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), `number:` as a [**label**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and t[he `,` as a sequence expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which is basically equivalent to

```
(number, origin: origin, destination: destination)
```

`origin:` is simply invalid at this position.

Comment: @user1010101 That doesn't affect the ASI issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton you are correct. It works now, thanks a ton, i would have never known this! I will accept your answer in 3 minutes as I can't at the moment.